# Find a suitable function

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose I'm given $f(x)$ and $f'(x)$ in closed form. Further suppose that $f(x)$ is continuously differentiable. I'm trying to find a nonconstant continuously differentiable function $g$ whose image is $\mathbb{R}$ that can be expressed in closed form such that

$$ \int g(f'(x)) dx$$

can be expressed in closed-form as a function of $f(x)$ or $f'(x)$ or both.

and $g(f'(x)) > 0$.

I've tried $g(x) = e^x$ and $g(x) = x^2$. However, using WolframAlpha, I find that the integral cannot be expressed in closed-form. Can I get a hint on this? Is this even possible?

Comment: Small typo: the $g$ in "$g(x)=x^2$" should be an $f$.

Comment: Something similar to the approach in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/534360/integration-of-fgx-by-substitution-creating-gx-dx-term-how-it-works) or [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/430420/functions-for-which-int-fgx-mathrm-dx-f-left-int-gx-dx-right) might work.